# Magento admin password

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I needed to change magento admin password so I went through following steps:

**1**)I exported the admin_user table into mydocumnets.

**2**)I run this Query:`UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';` and changed the password.

**3**)The new password did't work so I dropped the admin_user table and imported the already exported one but the previous password did not work too.

**4**)I manual changed the email address in admin_user table and using forgot password got a link to reset the password in my inbox and reseted the password but I could not log in using that password.

**5)** The password which is showing in env.php file is different from the one I set.

**Now**, I can't login to the admin panel and I am getting error 504 Getway time-out in customer view.

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your admin_user table before adn after updating? Not all, just row with user, that you try to modify.

Also, try to use SHA2() instead MD5() in your SQL query. Tell please, if it works for you.

Comment: @lllia Arefyev, Thanks for the suggestion now I can login into the admin panel but I get 504 Gateway Time-outnginx/1.3.7

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.3.7 in customer view.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `magento admin:user:create` command with the `--admin-user` and `--admin-password` options as discussed [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html#instgde-cli-admin).

You cannot create two administrators with the same e-mail though so use an alternative address and change it later.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to reset password or restore Magento admin info for your website, but we will give you the two most simple and effective methods. It is to restore via admin email and phpMyAdmin (via OIW Blog).

**1. Restoring username and password using your admin email**

As you know, all websites login page has a *“reset password”* or *“forgot your password”* section in case you lose your password. In the event that you forget your login password to the admin panel then there’s no need to be worried. Because you can restore your admin account within a few simple steps.

Firstly, open the admin panel login page. Then click on **Forgot your password?**
In the next screen (Forgot Password), you type your admin account’s email correctly in the box of **Email Address**. Afterward, click on **Retrieve Password**

Then, your login information to the admin panel (including username and password) will be sent to your email. You just need to click on the link in your email to reset the login information.

**2. Resetting your admin password using phpMyAdmin (Database**)

– Advantage: 100% successful
– Disadvantage: Quite complicated. You also need to have an understanding of server, cPanel, phpMyAdnin…

Firstly, you must have a Hosting Panel, VPS (or Dedicated Server)… admin account credentials of the website. Log in and scroll to Databases section (phpMyAdmin). Then, you need to find the correct Database (DB) of the website whose login information you forget.

If you have many DB in phpMyAdmin then you can specify the correct DB (username and password) associating with the website which you forget the login information by:

You use File Manager or FTP to open the file of file app/etc/local.xml (Magento version 1x), line 44-46:

```
<username><![CDATA[yourUsername]]></username> 
<password><![CDATA[yourPassword]]></password>
<dbname><![CDATA[yourDBname]]></dbname>
```

Next, you login phpMyAdmin with your username and password that you have in the above steps (normally you don’t have to re-login phpMyAdmin. When you login cPanel then it will redirect you to phpMyAdmin page). Then go to Database (already shown in the above steps) of your website to change your username and password. You need to find the table containing your admin panel’s username and password:

The default table `admin_user` (the name contains the prefix but still contains `_admin_user`).

You will see the *username* column and password of the username, but they are already encoded with MD5. Select the username that you want your password to be reset and click on **EDIT** button on the left side. Chane your *password* with MD5 options. Finally, click on **Go** button.

You're done #ohiwill